# Append Permanent Anchor Tags to a Page Dynamically - JQUERY/AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to permanent append an anchor that resulted from a form.

I am current doing a project that enable a user to have multiple profiles. Is there a way that enables the user after creating a form to click on a generated link which will to profile that will always be on the page.

pushing the data to the database and retrieving it for the profile is understandable but creating the links for the profiles using AJAX or JQUERY is a real brain teaser.

Comment: There is but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly havent, I wont lie Im horrible at javascript/jquery. Basically looking for a push in the right direction

Comment: Am sorry, we can only help you with problems you have encountered while coding. I don't even know exactly what you need. Show us your HTML codes...